# how to remove a certain set of characters from textbox

Tags: c#

Ok so I'm having a problem where my converter is for some reason adding the characters "%22" to the output textbox for some of the users of my program. All I need is something that i can put into a timer that detects if "%22" is detected in the textbox, and if it is detected, it will be deleted (leaving no spaces if it is the middle of a word)

```
if (metroTextbox2.Text.Contains("%22")
{
    metroTextbox2.Text.Remove("%22");
}
```

(That code above doesn't work btw. It leaves an error under ("%22") on the code "metroTextbox2.Text.Remove("%22");")

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: can u use javascript

Comment: instead of a timer you could use the [Invalidated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidated?view=netframework-4.8). It will be fired as soon as the textbox looses focus. Then you can remove your numbers

Comment: "leaving no spaces if it is the middle of a word" and if it is at the beginning or end? should it be replaced by spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove gets int parameter and not string.
Please use `String.Replace` method instead.

I.e.

```
metroTextbox2.Text = metroTextbox2.Text.Replace("%22", string.Empty);
```

Comment: @ImmortalDonkey And fix the closing parenthesis of the if condition :)

Comment: @grek40 Yeah, that was true. I just removed the if completely since if the string does not contain such sequence, Replace will do nothing. Just useless string traversal

Comment: Hello @ImmortalDonkey. If the answer is ok for you, please consider [marking it as accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I would be very glad as well as it will be easier to find proper solution by other people having similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `REMOVE` try use `REPLACE` Like this :

```
if (!metroTextbox2.Text.Contains("%22")
{
    metroTextbox2.Text.Replace("%22", "");
}
```